# How to get value from url PHP

Tags: php

If someone is loading my site like **www.example.com/value?=something** 
it will add the value to a mysql database

Like google https://www.google.com/search?q=something

I think it's easy but i'm a extremely noob to PHP and don't how to do it.

Comment: Hey WeeHee. please learn this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Your example is not valid. It's `someaddress.com/?someKey=someValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called query parameters.

```
<?php

$param1 = $_GET['q']; // something for http://localhost/script.php?q=something
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: That was helpful

Answer (score 0):

catch the value in a variable using

```
$variable = $_GET['value']
```

and then add $variable to your database.